# Having trouble finding value with for-in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to loop through this array's objects elements and return 'gotcha, bill' when the 'for in' loop finds the value 'bill'. However, it only seems to return 'not him' four times. I've skimmed over it several times and I'm not sure what I am missing. This is my first time using a for in loop, so I could be misunderstanding how it works.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
var names = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];

function findBill(array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for(let key in array[i]) {
        if(key === 'bill') {
          return console.log('gotcha, bill');
        } else {
          console.log('not him');
        }
      }
    }
  }

findBill(names)
```

Comment: `bill` is not a key. `bill` is a value.

Comment: Hm, perhaps I misunderstood the reference I was looking at and came to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: It's worth learning the array methods so you don't need so much code. You can find bill with : `let bill = names.find(({name}) => name == 'bill')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for..in` iterates over an object's *keys*. Since `bill` is a value, not a key, the `(key === 'bill')` test will never evaluate to `true`.

If you wanted to iterate over the object's values instead, use `Object.values`, and since it sounds like you want to *find* the `bill` object, you can use `.find`:

```js
var names = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];

function findBill(array) {
  return array.find((obj) => (
    Object.values(obj).includes('bill')
  ))
};

console.log(findBill(names))
```

If you know in advance that the value will be in the `name` property, then just test that property, rather than using `Object.values`:

```js
var names = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];

function findBill(array) {
  return array.find((obj) => (
    obj.name === 'bill'
  ))
};

console.log(findBill(names))
```

Comment: No, `'bill'` is a value. Objects have key-value pairs - `name: 'bill'` is such a pair. The `name` is the key and the `'bill'` is the value

Answer (score 1):

Here. I changed your `for` loop to `forEach` but that is not the main thing that solves your problem. It is how you access the object's property. I use `forEach` because it will be easier (for me) to get the desired data from the object.

```js
var names = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];

function findBill(array) {
  array.forEach(function(person){
    if(person.name === 'bill') {
      return console.log('gotcha, bill');
    } else {
      console.log('not him');
    }
  });
}

findBill(names)
```

And this is how it should be if you insist on using `for` loop.

```js
var names = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];

function findBill(array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if(array[i].name === 'bill') {
        return console.log('gotcha, bill');
      } else {
        console.log('not him');
      }
    }
  }

findBill(names)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using the for in loop to follow along with the tutorial. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`key` is exactly that--the keys of each object, namely, `name` or `age`. You need to actually index into the array at the correct index, then access the value for the key you're inspecting in the loop with `if (array[i][key] === 'bill')`.

Here's a working example:

```js
var names = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];

function findBill(array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for(let key in array[i]) {
        if(array[i][key] === 'bill') {
          return console.log('gotcha, bill');
        } else {
          console.log('not him');
        }
      }
    }
  }

findBill(names);
```

However, the extra loop isn't necessary and causes logic errors because you might have some other key, say, `buffalo` that happens to have the value `"bill"` and you'll wind up with a false positive. You know the key, so you can simply search the array for any object with the matching value for that key:

```js
var names = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];

console.log(names.find(e => e.name === "bill"));
```

Lastly, I recommend avoiding `console.log` in functions, which is a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) that limits reusability. `console.log` returns `undefined` after printing, so it's misleading to return this, even in simple or contrived examples.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two loops for this. In fact you can use the `Array.find()` method to find the object you need and do with it what you need:

```
const people = [{name: 'steven', age: 22}, {name: 'bill', age: 13}];
const findByName = (data, name) => data.find(cur => cur.name === name);
const Bill = findByName(people, 'bill');

if (Bill === null) { console.log(`could not find bill`); }
else { console.log(`bill is ${Bill.age} years old`); }
```